# Defining python type hints for list of a weakref object

Tags: python, weak-references, type-hinting

I haven't found how to give type hints indication when using weakrefs.

```
from typing import List
import weakref
class MyObject:
    def __init(self, foo)
        self.foo = foo
o1 = MyObject(1)
o2 = MyObject(2)
my_list: List[weakref] = [weakref.ref(o1), weakref.ref(o2)]
```

Is there a way to say that `my_list` is a `list` of `weakref` to `MyObject`, something like:

```
my_list: List[Weakref[MyObject]] = [weakref.ref(o1), weakref.ref(o2)]
```

?

Comment: "no runtime involved here" - if you're going to run your code, then runtime behavior matters. When I say `ReferenceType[Whatever]` "doesn't actually work at runtime", I mean that it actually *outright throws an error* and fails to run.

Comment: Ok sorry, I read too fast your comments and missunderstood the purpose of the discussion. So accepted a bit fast, without testing indeed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can find this information by consulting [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), a repository of type hints for the standard library and some popular 3rd party modules.

Specifically, if we look at the stubs for the [`weakref` module](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/weakref.pyi), we can see that it re-exports `ref` from the [`_weakref` module](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/_weakref.pyi). And from there, we see that `ref` is defined to be equivalent to the `ReferenceType` class, which is defined to be generic (and is also re-exported from `weakref`).

Putting these pieces together, we can give your `my_list` variable a type hint that looks like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List
from weakref import ref, ReferenceType

# ...snip...

my_list: List[ReferenceType[MyObject]] = [...]
```

Somewhat interestingly, it's also ok to do this:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List
from weakref import ref

# ...snip...

my_list: List[ref[MyObject]] = [...]
```

Basically, `ref` is also an alias to `ReferenceType` so we can use both types interchangeably.

I would personally use `ReferenceType`, but that's mostly because I'm just so used to types starting with capital letters. (Or, if that type hint starts getting too verbose, I'd maybe define a custom type alias `Ref = ReferenceType`).

Note that the `from __future__ import annotations` line is available only on Python 3.7+. If you're using an older version of Python, you'll need to make your type hints be strings manually:

```
from typing import List
from weakref import ref

# ...snip...

my_list: "List[ReferenceType[MyObject]]" = [...]

# Or:

my_list: List["ReferenceType[MyObject]"] = [...]
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work at runtime - the real `weakref.ReferenceType` is not generic.

Comment: @user2357112 -- ah, you can work around that by making your type hint a string (`my_list: "List[ReferenceType[MyObject]]" = ...`). If you're using Python 3.7+, you can instead add a `from __future__ import annotations`, which will convert all type hints into strings automatically.

Comment: You can do that, but [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) will still fail.

Comment: @user2357112 -- lI think in that case, you're mostly out of luck. Type hints are meant to be useful mostly for static analysis, and analyzing them at runtime isn't very well-supported. I suppose the last thing you could try is defining a [custom protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html) that basically copies the definition of ReferenceType -- but I have no idea how protocols will interact with functions that do that kind of runtime introspection.

Comment: indeed your examples lead to:
`File "<ipython-input-61-5860728006fe>", line 1, in <module>r:   ReferenceType[MyObject] = weakref.ref(o1) TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @beesleep -- my second comment has some workarounds for that.

Comment: Could you please edit you answer then ? Because, what is proposed in the answer itself doesn't work... Thanks

Comment: @beesleep -- sure.

Comment: the main problem is that ReferenceType is not a valid type